# Set AppLab Mouse Coordinates

Tags: app-lab

I've seen how to get the mouse coordinates in AppLab (which if you don't know is a code.org lab which uses JS and a very strange library). However, I want to **set** the coordinates. I've seen this link: [App Lab Mouse Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012529/app-lab-mouse-coordinates)
But it doesn't help. How would I set the mouse coordinates? (In other words, move the mouse using the computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately is not entirely possible to set the user's mouse coordinates in code.org.
If I do ever find a workaround I will be sure to contact you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot manipulate the mouse pointer on App Lab. It's not even possible to do with regular Javascript.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).